# Python variable replacement in Sqlite3 INSERT statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

Is there a way to use Python's variable replacement when updating Sqlite data targeting a known rowid? I am trying to say something like:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Words(rowid,f1,f2) VALUES(?,?,?)', [rowid,2,3])
```

The problem is that this fails with error:

```
sqlite3.IntegrityError: PRIMARY KEY must be unique
```

I want to write a list of values into the table's existing record without changing the rowid number. What's the accepted way to update all fields from a list of values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use [`UPDATE`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) instead of `INSERT`:

```
cursor.execute('UPDATE Words SET f1=?, f2=? WHERE rowid=?', [2, 3, rowid])
```

This tells the database to update the `f1` and `f2` columns with new values, for all rows where `rowid` matches your specified value.

Alternatively, use the [`INSERT OR REPLACE` syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html); if a uniqueness constraint (such as the primary key not being unique) is violated, an `UPDATE` is issued instead, but if `rowid` is not yet present a new row will be inserted:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Words(rowid,f1,f2) VALUES(?,?,?)', [rowid,2,3])
```